# Standard text representation for floating-point numbers

Tags: serialization, floating-point

Is there a standard text representation for the floating-point numbers that is supported by the most popular languages?

What is the standard fro representing infinities and NaNs?

Comment: There is no standard. Many programming languages accept some variant of *sign digits . digits e sign digits*, where various parts are optional, in certain combinations. For example `+3.4` and `-9e-13`. There is less commonality among representing infinities and NaNs.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a general consensus, unfortunately.

However, there seems to be some convergence on hexadecimal notation for floats. See pg. 57/58 of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

The advantage of this notation is that you can precisely represent the value of the float as represented by the machine without worrying about any loss of precision. See this page for examples: https://www.exploringbinary.com/hexadecimal-floating-point-constants/

Note that `NaN` and `Infinity` values are not supported by hexadecimal-floats. There seems to be no general consensus on how to write these. Most languages actually don't even allow writing these as constants, so you resort to expressions such as `0/0` or `1/0` etc. instead.

Since you tagged this question with `serialization`, I'd recommend simply serializing using the bit-pattern you have for the float value. This will cost you  8-characters for single-precision and 16-characters for double-precision, (64 bits and 128 bits respectively, assuming 8-bit per character). Perhaps not the most efficient, but it'll ensure you can encode all possible values and transmit precisely.